# Left sidebar not showing after I add it

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been trying to add a left side bar to a child theme I made based on the [GreatMag](https://wordpress.org/themes/greatmag/) theme which comes with one sidebar by default (right sidebar). I can't get the left sidebar to show up, I've looked up quite a few tutorial on how to do this, such as [this one](https://www.phpflow.com/misc/wordpress-3/how-to-add-sidebar-to-a-wordpress-theme/) and I understand what needs to be done:

1. Create a child theme
2. Register the new sidebar in **functions.php** file
3. Add a new template file in my case **sidebar-left.php**
4. Style the new sidebar - I floated it left in css
5. Call the sidebar in the file on the page you want it to appear: **get_sidebar('sidebar-2');**

I registered the new, left sidebar like this:

```
register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Left Sidebar', 'greatmag' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-2',
        'description'   => esc_html__( 'Add widgets here.', 'greatmag' ),
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
```

This is what sidebar-left.php looks like:

```
<?php
/**
 * The sidebar containing the main widget area.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package GreatMag
 */

if ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) ) {
    return;
}
?>

<aside id="left" class="widget-area col-md-2 sidebar-area" role="complementary">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ); ?>
</aside><!-- #secondary -->
```

I changed the assigned classes for both sidebar to: col-md-2 since the main content is col-md-8

Left Sidebar is showing up in the dashboard, so I recon it's being registered:
[image]

But only the Right Sidebar is showing in the widgets area:
[image]

Nor is it showing on the home page:
[image]

I've also looked at a [few themes that have left and right sidebars](https://beautifulthemer.com/free-wordpress-themes-with-left-and-right-sidebars/) to see how it's done but was ultimately unsuccessful, so if someone can explain to me what am I doing wrong I'd be most appreciative!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is the following:

- You're `registering` the sidebar, which makes it available in the widget areas.
- You're defining your Sidebar layout in the `sidebar-left.php` file
- But you're **not** actually telling your theme to pull in the sidebar anywhere.

Looking at the theme briefly, they call the sidebar with `get_sidebar()` in a few of the theme files. So you have two main options.

**One:**
Copy those files to your child theme and add `get_sidebar('sidebar-left');` in the same files, placement may vary, but these are the files that invoke the sidebar that way:

Using this method you can also create a new page template such as `two-sidebars.php` and place the `get_sidebar('sidebar-left');` code in that file, giving you the option to use both sidebars on a per-page basis (or even just the left sidebar if you wish, by removing the `get_sidebar();` line)

[image: Screenshot of Theme Structure]

**Two:**
Hook in the sidebar with [`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/).

I'd probably stick with the first option, since it's how the theme's default sidebar is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function wpb_widgets_init() {

        register_sidebar( array(
            'name' =>__( 'Sidebar Title', 'wpb'),
            'id' => 'sidebar-new',
            'description' => __( 'Description goes here', 'wpb' ),
            'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget' => '</aside>',
            'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title' => '</h3>',
        ) );
        }

    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_widgets_init' );


    //to display 

    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-new' ) ) : ?>
        <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-new' ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Please refer following links to display sidebar
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_sidebar/
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-dynamic-widget-ready-sidebars-in-wordpress/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19217104)

Comment: @ADyson I agreed, I have modified my answer, Thanks for attention.

Comment: @ADyson Please remove down vote if you have given, as I have updated my answer with  example.

Comment: I haven't voted either way. I only saw it in the Review queue, which auto-generated my comment when I flagged it